# Why does this method not add items to a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, linq

I am trying to add items from a database into a list instead of adding them statically from aspx.  I made this method, and although it compiles, it doesn't add any list items to my drop down list.  Here is some code, and I am willing to provide more if need be.  The method in question is addListItemsToPage().

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace EndophthalmitisDatabase {
    public partial class DataEntry : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            addListItemsToPage();
        }

        protected void addListItemsToPage() {
            EndophthalmitisDBDataContext dbContext = new EndophthalmitisDBDataContext();

            for (int i=0;  dbContext.Hospital_Datas.Count() < i; i++){
                int id = dbContext.Hospital_Datas.ElementAt(i).HospitalID;
                string str = dbContext.Hospital_Datas.ElementAt(i).Hospital_Name;

                ListItem li = new ListItem();
                li.Text = str;
                li.Value = id.ToString();

                hospitalDDL.Items.Add(li);
            }

        }

        protected void submitEndoDataBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (EndophthalmitisDBDataContext dbContext = new EndophthalmitisDBDataContext()) {
                Occurrence_Data occData = new Occurrence_Data
                {
                    LastName = lastNameTB.Text,
                    FirstName = firstNameTB.Text,
                    MRN = int.Parse(mrnTB.Text),
                    DateOfOccurence = DateOfOccurenceCal.SelectedDate,
                    InterventionProcedureDone = int.Parse(InterventionDDL.SelectedValue),
                    PreOccurrencePhysician = int.Parse(InterventionSurgeonDDL.SelectedValue),
                    LabsSent = labsSentCB.Checked,
                    PrecipitatingCausePreviousSurgery = int.Parse(preCauseDDL.SelectedValue),
                    PostOccurrencePhysician = int.Parse(preSurgeonDDL.SelectedValue),
                    DateOfPreviousSurgery = datePrecipitatingCal.SelectedDate,
                    Hospital = int.Parse(hospitalDDL.SelectedValue),
                    AdditionalInformation = moreInfoTB.Text
                };

                lastNameTB.Text = "";
                firstNameTB.Text = "";
                mrnTB.Text = "";
                labsSentCB.Checked = false;
                moreInfoTB.Text = "";

                dbContext.Occurrence_Datas.InsertOnSubmit(occData);
                dbContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainSite.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataEntry.aspx.cs" Inherits="EndophthalmitisDatabase.DataEntry" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
     <div class="formBox">
        <p style="text-align: center">Please use the area below to enter Data.</p>
        <div class = "dataEntryForm">
            <form id = "occurrenceForm" runat = "server">
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Last Name</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:TextBox ID = "lastNameTB" runat = "server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Last Name</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:TextBox ID = "firstNameTB" runat = "server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">MRN</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:TextBox ID = "mrnTB" runat = "server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Date of Occurence</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:Calendar ID="DateOfOccurenceCal" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Intervention</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="InterventionDDL" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="1">Phaco</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="2">Injection</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="3">Retina Surgery</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="4">Transplant</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="5">Other</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Intervention Surgeon</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="InterventionSurgeonDDL" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="8">Tabin</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="9">Crandal</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Labs sent</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="labsSentCB" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Precipitating Cause</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="preCauseDDL" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="1">Phaco</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="2">Injection</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="3">Retina Surgery</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="4">Transplant</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="5">Other</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Precipitating Surgeon</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="preSurgeonDDL" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="8">Tabin</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value ="9">Crandal</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Data of Precipitating Cause</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:Calendar ID ="datePrecipitatingCal" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Hospital</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID ="hospitalDDL" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">Additional Information</div>
                    <div class ="dataRowEntrance">
                        <asp:TextBox ID ="moreInfoTB" runat="server" Rows ="100"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="dataRow">
                    <div class ="dataRowText">
                        <asp:Button ID ="submitEndoDataBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick ="submitEndoDataBtn_Click"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is this Proof of Concept?  Or "real" code?  If the latter, please read http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AReminderOnThreeMultiTierLayerArchitectureDesignBroughtToYouByMyLateNightFrustrations.aspx

Comment: The way your code is structured it would be better to materialize the list completely from the db context first instead of always referencing the DbSet.

Comment: Its "real code"  Im not sure what you mean...

Comment: How would I go about doing that?  Im very new to Linq to SQL

Comment: if you don't know what i mean by "real code", then please read the article and restructure your code.  the gui layer should not know about your dataAccess tool of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop condition is wrong, its need to be opposite

```
for (int i=0;  i < dbContext.Hospital_Datas.Count(); i++)
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes its the simplest things that I overlook.

Answer (score 3):

1. Always wrap your `DbContext` creation in a `using` statement or dispose of it in your containing class if its scoped at the class level. Yours is scoped in the method and your code abondons it without disposing of it (bad practice!)
2. Your `for` statement was wrong but you really do not need a `for`, you could use a `foreach` which would be much easier to read OR use data binding as suggested by Ashkan.
3. You could also condense it down to a single statement, see the OR in the comment below in the code. This uses a `Lambda` statement.

Code:

```
protected void addListItemsToPage() {
    // wrap this in a using statement so the connection is closed and disposed
    using(EndophthalmitisDBDataContext dbContext = new EndophthalmitisDBDataContext())
    {
        // replaced your wrong for statement with a foreach because you do not need a for statement (you are not using the indexer in a way that added any benifit)
        foreach(var hospital in dbContext.Hospital_Datas)
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Text = hospital.Hospital_Name;
            li.Value = hospital.HospitalID;

            hospitalDDL.Items.Add(li);
        }


        // OR you could write it as a single statement
        hospitalDDL.AddRange(dbContext.Hospital_Datas.Select(hospital => new ListItem(){Text = hospital.Hospital_Name, Value = hospital.HospitalID}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I am very new to Linq to SQL; why should I dispose of dbcontext?  What other objects should I dispose of?  I will try to add what you advised.

Comment: @Darokrithia - Anything that implements the interface `System.IDisposable`. These are typically types that use external resources like database connections or filestreams, or network streams, etc. If you do not call `Dispose` when you are done with them then you potentially leave the resource open until garbage collection happens (maybe, could be promoted to gen2). A using statement ensures that when the scope of the block is left the Dispose is called (you can only use using with disposable types). In your case you would be leaving database connections open.

Answer (score 1):

OMG, that is very bad practice. you will call the DB everytime you enter the loop.

```
 protected void addListItemsToPage() {
    EndophthalmitisDBDataContext dbContext = new   EndophthalmitisDBDataContext();

   hospitalDDL.DataTextField = "Hospital_Name";
    hospitalDDL.DataValueField = "HospitalID"

    hospitalDDL.DataSource = dbContext.Hospital_Datas.ToList();
    hospitalDDL.DataBind();

  }
```